# How to install a stack and package manually in Fuerte?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I'm trying to install the rosbridge package from the brown_remotelab stack. The tutorials and answers that I've found on the web give more-or-less the following procedure for doing this:

```
# Enter directory where my stacks are kept
roscd
# Checkout repository
svn co http://brown-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distribution/brown_remotelab
# Enter directory of package
cd brown_remotelab/rosbridge
# Build package and it's dependencies
rosmake --rosdep-install
```

This doesn't work for me.
For starters when I try to run rosmake --rosdep-install I get the error message:

```
rosmake: error: no such option: --rosdep-install
```

So it looks like the --rosdep-install option is deprecated. Also if I try running without that option I get:

```
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...
[ rosmake ] No package or stack specified.  And current directory 'rosbridge' is not a package name or stack name.
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: []
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /root/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120619-160854
[ rosmake ] Expanded args [] to:
[]
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.
```

Similarly, if I try to use roscd, rospackage or rosstack on the newly downloaded stack and packages I get errors like

```
roscd: No such package/stack 'rosbridge'
```

or

```
[rosstack] Error: stack/package brown_remotelab not found
```

So it looks like ROS doesn't know where to find them. This is after re-sourcing my setup.bash.

In short: **What is the complete procedure for downloading and installing a ROS stack and package from source in ROS Fuerte?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36784/how-to-install-a-stack-and-package-manually-in-fuerte?/) by [Shum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2550/shum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2012-06-18**:
In my opinion, you should first "roscreate-pkg" with the corresponding name and then svn checkout in this folder. This way the package will be known by ros and rosmake can work (not tested on fuerte).

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-06-18**:
You only call roscreate-pkg when you really want to create a new package, not when you check something out. It wouldn't help anyway since it seems like the checkout was simply not in the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2012-06-19**:
Ok, right, thanks for bringing some light on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You didn't put the checkout into your ros workspace. The cleanest way of managing your workspace is probably by using [rosws](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/rosinstall/html/rosws_tutorial.html). You can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install -U rosinstall
```

Now you can set up a ros workspace:

```
rosws init ~/ros_workspace /opt/ros/fuerte
```

Now source the newly generated setup.bash:

```
source ~/ros_workspace/setup.bash
```

You can also replace the line `source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash` by the line above to always use your workspace. Just don't forget to remove setting of the variable ROS_WORKSPACE if you do so in your .bashrc since that is done by rosws' setup.bash.

Now add the repository you want to check out:

```
rosws set brown_remotelab "http://brown-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distribution/brown_remotelab" --svn
rosws update brown_remotelab
```

Source `~/ros_workspace/setup.bash` again or open a new terminal to make sure that your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is updated and try running

```
rosmake brown_remotelab
```

`rosmake --rosdep-install` is not supported in Fuerte anymore. See [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/36746/equivalent-of-rosdep-install-in-fuerte/?answer=36768#post-id-36768).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7